# What's the Eye of a Hurricane called in Chinese/Pinyin?

Tags: translation, pinyin

For a role playing game I'm joining, my character is a monk of Chinese origin.

Trying to come up with a name I thought of "Eye of (the) Hurricane/Typhoon" as the monk is a very calm character caught in the turbulence of the real world outside of the monastery. I tried to look for a Chinese translation of which I would want to use the Pinyin equivalent, but I couldn't find it.

Does anyone know what the eye of a hurricane or typhoon is called in Chinese and if so, could you provide me with a Pinyin alternative?

I tried this dictionary: http://tool.nciku.com/pinyin-translator/#results
But the server isn't responding. Couldn't find any other good dictionaries.

Comment: http://www.nciku.cn/search/en/detail/eye/1704625: definition 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's 风眼(feng1 yan3) or 台风眼(tai2 feng1 yan3), simply the word-by-word translation to the English word "Eye of (the) Hurricane/Typhoon".

You can see it on the wiki: http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A2%A8%E7%9C%BC